# What is mean by 3 level program memory lock?

Tags: atmel

I am building my first microcontroller programmer using [at89c51](http://www.atmel.com/dyn/resources/prod_documents/doc0265.pdf). In its documentation I have read that it support 3 level programming lock. But I did not find a simple explanation of this term.

Will somebody explain what are memory locks and what is mean by 3 level in this context?

Comment: Can you give us a direct source of that information? This will help us to put it into correct context.

Answer (score 1):

Its purpose seems to be to restrict access to the program memory, to prevent reading out the program from a controller.

There are three levels (plus one unprotected level), see the bottom of page 5.